# why memset does not set all the memory?

Tags: c

My code looks like:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *mm;
    int mem_size = 1 << 30;
    long *ptr, *end;

    mm = (char *) mmap(NULL, mem_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
    assert(mm != MAP_FAILED);
    memset(mm, 0xff, mem_size);
    end = (long *) mm + mem_size;

    for(ptr = (long *) mm ; ptr < end ; ptr++){
        if((*ptr) != ~(long)0){
            printf("At %p found 0x%" PRIx64 "\n", ptr, *ptr);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

I set all my memory to 0xff to fill it with ones. I would expect that the print never executes but it is not so. When I search for a memory region that contains a bit set to zero I find an address into the memory region. Where is the error?

Comment: Describe where in the memory you get the error.  Is it near the beginning, near the end?  Is it always at the same place relative to the end of memory?

Comment: "`end = (long *) mm + mem_size;`" why do you cast `mm` to `long*`? your `end` will be way beyond the memory you `mmap()`ed.

Comment: Note: `(long *) mm + mem_size` will point to something *way* beyond the end of memory, because mem_size will be multiplied by the size of long before the addition. You probably mean `(long *)(mm + memsize)`.

Comment: btw `PRIx64` is for `uint64_t`, yet you're using *long*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're scanning *way* past the end of the mapped memory.

```
end = (long *) mm + mem_size;
```

You convert `mm` to a `long*`. Adding `mem_size` to that pointer value advances the pointer by `mem_size * sizeof (long)` bytes.

Change that to:

```
end = (long *)(mm + mem_size);
```

Comment: @EmanueleVannacci: Precedence errors like this can be subtle and hard to catch; count yourself lucky that you only wasted a single day.  When in doubt, use parentheses.

Comment: Another option is to declare `long *mm` and then use `&mm[mem_size]`